# Mathematical logic book that uses a proof assistant?

Tags: logic, reference-request, foundations, computer-assisted-proofs

I'm looking for an introductory book on mathematical logic that also discusses an implementation of its logic in a proof assistant. It seems to me this would be a great way to learn mathematical logic, since many concepts would become very clear and concrete when implemented in a computer program. But I have never seen such a book.

Preferably, the book would introduce the language of the proof assistant assuming no prior knowledge, and encourage the reader to use it at various points.

**EDIT**

I like the answers posted so far, and want to keep this open for a while to collect other recommendations in one place. However, after opening it, I also found the following excellent resources linked in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2539841/computer-assisted-proof-for-undergraduates) question, namely [this](https://avigad.github.io/formal_methods_in_education/) list of resources and [this](https://leanprover.github.io/logic_and_proof/logic_and_proof.pdf) book/compilation of notes by Jeremy Avigad. These resources seem like the type of thing I was looking for, and might be helpful to others who stumble on this post.

**EDIT 2**

One feature I would ***really*** like to see, which I haven't seen in the suggestions so far, is a book that also formalizes its meta-logic within a proof assistant. For example, I would love a book that proves (for example) a soundness theorem, and shows how such a proof could be implemented with a proof assistant.

Then again, I'd be surprised if such a resource exists, since no mathematical logic books (that I've seen) even mention the idea of formalizing meta-logic.

Comment: Would the texts from the Open Logic Project count, where they have a hand-developed web tool for formal verification of proofs in their systems?  Or are you asking specifically for something using a general-purpose proof assistant?

Comment: @DanielSchepler I'm fine with any particular software—as long as it is being used for instructive purposes alongside a resource for teaching mathematical logic. Seems like OLP is a great resource, although I can't find their web tool for proof verification, which you mentioned.

Comment: To get your feet wet, you might consider my proof checker freeware downloadable from my homepage at http://www.dcproof.com with accompanying tutorial. It was designed to introduce students to the basic methods of proof. It is based on a simplified form of natural deduction and set theory that seems to be implicitly used in most math text books (not standard FOL or ZFC).

Comment: Concerning your second edit: In the draft I have linked, soundness and completeness of classical propositional logic are shown at the end of the chapter on Natural Deduction. Formalizing the full-meta logic a book uses is intricate question; the book then explicitly needs to make a distinction between its meta-logic and the object-logic it wants to study.  Usually the proof-assistant (and its logic) are used as the meta-logic in which results are discussed. Then to formalize(!) all the intricacies off the proof assistant logic really is its own challenge altogether.

Comment: Dan's website is not useful for actual mathematical work, such as [its worthless proof of the Schroder-Bernstein theorem](https://www.dcproof.com/CBS.htm).

Comment: For those interested in Proof Assistants, there is a new proposed SE site [ProofAssistants](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/126242/proof-assistants?referrer=Njg4YTJmMjYwOTIxNjdkNGEyMmZkNzE0Y2M4YmFhOTY3OWVmNDUwNWM3ZmFlMjYwYTRiYzZiZWY1ODg5ZjdiMqfBIyhShuHO9QbGuJfVwOYRvfVgPfbJQrn2UOFTeOe-0)

Answer (score 7):

I would strongly recommend John Harrison's *Handbook of Practical Logic and Automated Reasoning*. The programming examples are more to do with how to implement proof assistants and decision procedures rather than how to use a proof assistant, but I think they meet your desire for implementations that clarify the key concepts. The examples are all given in the functional programming language [OCaml](https://ocaml.org).

Concerning the second edit: I think it is implicit in most texts on mathematical logic that the subject can be formalised in a suitable foundation system such as ZF. In the mathematical logic literature this becomes important and is made explicit in work on [independence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_(mathematical_logic)), In the world of proof assistants, self-formalisation with a view to increased assurance and understanding has been of intererest for many years. E.g., see this paper on [self-verification of HOL](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/s10817-015-9357-x.pdf) and the references therein. I think the overall principles of a formalised meta-logic are probably more instructive than the fine details  of the formalisation.

Answer (score 5):

Try fundamental proof methods in computer science.it uses Athena as a proof assistant.It teaches both logic with language.

If you find that complex here a simple one-
https://staff.washington.edu/jon/flip/www/userguide-nd.html
It works with Python 2.7.

Answer (score 2):

Books having an accompanying proof assistant for their logic is one way to look at it, but it also works the other way around: Most proof assistants implement some particular (usually constructive) logic and therefore books about the proof assistant are already books about this logic.

Here are some resources about [Coq](https://coq.inria.fr/):

- [Coq'Art [Bertot]](https://www.labri.fr/perso/casteran/CoqArt/)
- [Sofware Foundations Series [Pierce]](https://softwarefoundations.cis.upenn.edu/) In particular book 1 introduces constructive logic inside of Coq.
- [Certified Programming with Dependent Types [Chlipala]](http://adam.chlipala.net/cpdt/)
- [Modeling and Proving in Computational Type Theory Using Coq [Smolka]](https://www.ps.uni-saarland.de/%7Esmolka/drafts/icl2021.pdf) is a still evolving draft of a book, which is the basis of a lecture and has accompanying Coq files [on github](https://github.com/uds-psl/MPCTT/tree/main/coq#directory-of-coq-files). It's talking about the proof assistant in a less direct way.

The [Lean](http://leanprover.github.io/) Community site has a page on recommended [learning resources](https://leanprover-community.github.io/learn.html).

And let's not forget the HoTT stuff:

- [Homotopy Type Theory:
  Univalent Foundations of Mathematics](https://homotopytypetheory.org/book/) There are libraries for several proof assistants (e.g. Coq) which allow you to work in HoTT.